# Pytest add a new file under src and get the tests to see it

Tags: python, testing, configuration, pytest

A newb where pytest is concerned.

I set up my structure: my_proj\src with the app files under src, and my_proj\tests with the test files under there. Following [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Python-Testing-pytest-Brian-Okken/dp/1680502409/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=python%20testing%20with%20pytest&qid=1625336332&sr=8-1), I then added files like my_proj\setup.py, which looks like this currently:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my_proj',
    version='0.1.0',
    license='proprietary',
    ...    
    packages=find_packages(where='src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    install_requires=[], 
    extras_require={},
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'py_lib = py_lib.cli:py_lib_cli',
        ]
    },
)
```

Then, as per the book, I ran

```
> pip install -e .
```

... and by some magic beyond my understanding this then set up things so that under the my_proj\tests side of things, the test files were able to import .py files from under my_proj\src.

Then I wanted to add a new .py file to the src files, i.e. the application files, the files under my_proj\src. But the tests are completely unable to see it: "No module named 'xxx'".

I tried `pip install -e .` again. I also tried `pip develop .`, and I tried the `--no-cache-dir flag`. I even tried running setup.py directly, which apparently is not recommended.

Then I found that under my_proj\src there is a directory which has been generated, my_proj.egg-info. One of the files under there is SOURCES.txt, which appears to list all the files in the project. My new .py file under \src is indeed listed there. And yet the test framework apparently can't see it.

Finally I tried uninstalling the thing:

```
pip uninstall my_proj
...
Proceed (y/n)? y 
...
```

and reinstalling

```
pip install -e .
```

Tests **still** can't see (i.e. import) the new file. Grrr.

Can anyone explain this and tell me how to resolve the problem?

**Edit**

In answer to the comment: I added a new file, under src\utils: new_file.py, like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
conc_fh = False
line_of_stars=50*'*' + '\n'
```

The test file is my_proj\tests\unit\test_misc_utils.py. I am usually running pytest from my_proj\tests\unit, although I have also tried the parent and grandparent directories. In that file this is the import line:

```
import utils.new_file
```

Same fail (for the new file). Then I tried all those possible remedies again.

I also tried deleting things like the my_proj.egg-info directory, and the my_proj\tests.pytest_cache and my_proj\tests\__pycache__ directories.

I can only conclude (provisionally) that something under site-packages in the virtual environment is incapable of updating correctly.

I have even tried `pip uninstall pytest` and reinstall, followed by `pip install -e .` again. Even then: NO!

Can someone confirm that adding a file works without problems for them (ideally on a W10 OS)?

NB this is the fail  output:

```
______________________________________ ERROR collecting unit/test_misc_utils.py _______________________________________
ImportError while importing test module 'D:\My documents\software projects\EclipseWorkspace\my_proj\tests\unit\test_misc_utils.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
c:\users\mike\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests\unit\test_misc_utils.py:3: in <module>
    import utils.new_file
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.new_file'
```

**Later**

I completely created a new project, by copying the old one, but setting up an entirely new virtual environment.

I then installed pytest again, and again ran `pip install -e .`, and then `pytest tests/unit` from the project directory.

To my utter amazement, once again, these two new files, the ones recently created (and copied in the process of making a new project), and only them, failed to be recognised and could not be imported.

Now I am totally baffled. It would appear that there is something about the nature of these files which is "defective". I've tried looking at the lines in them, for things like spurious Unicode characters. Nothing so far...

Comment: You are doing everything right (by the book :), as far as I can see - I think the problem has probably to do with your added module. Can you show the file structure of your project, and what you did add? What error message do you get from `pytest`?

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` file in `utils` package, if not create one, and see if it works?

Comment: @FelixKJose thanks, I have `__init__.py` there, indeed.

Comment: To be clear: the new files are correctly imported and used in the production code, but not in the test, is this correct?

Comment: Could you try `pip install .`? Then you should be able to successfully import the module and the functions in your test.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Correct, these files import fine in a normal production run (e.g. `>python src\utils`).  This only happens when I'm trying to run pytest.

Comment: @mikerodent Sorry, I had read your question but I missed to give entire detail in the comment. I was able to resolve the issue you mentioned, as you mentioned  when I added a new package with a new module, that class was not available in my corresponding pytest, but when I run `pip install .`/ `pip install -e .`, the package becomes available and I was able to run the pytest. The only difference is I am using MacOS. But again sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Think I finally worked it out.

The question is: what is available (for import) to the modules and files under "my_proj/tests". I believe this is determined by setup.py (as outlined in the referenced book). The most bare-boned version of this is:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='my_proj2',
    py_modules=['my_proj2']
)
```

When you then run `pip install -e .` (note dot), this means that modules under my_proj2/src become available for import. But perhaps not everything. The downloadable files (again for the book) include a module [root]/src/tasks ... and under that is an `__init__.py`, which explicitly imports various variables and classes from that module, **for re-export to the test classes**.

This approach (including anything you want to import into tests in `__init__.py` of an application module) is not the only way of accessing stuff in modules under [root]/src when running tests. Any valid path under [root]/src appears to work. I have no idea why it failed on my previous attempts. Maybe the previous setup.py file (tweaked from the downloaded version) contained something complicated which interfered with things.

Comment: So it worked out in the end, but you still don't know what went wrong? Anyway, glad that you could get it to work - I had no clue what went wrong here...